# XenServer has two processor, but only one is visible

Tags: xenserver, intel, xeon

I have a pool of two identical HP DL 360 G7 (dual processor Intel Xeon X5650), with two processors installed (the BIOS show both), running XenServer 6.5. Intel says that this processor has six cores (12 threads - but I disabled hyperthreading)

http://ark.intel.com/products/47922/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X5650-12M-Cache-2_66-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI

But, on my XenServers, only six cores are visible on the top command, or on /proc/cpuinfo...

My question is: Have I to do something in XenServer to see/use two processors?

If not, could my system have hardware problems? in both servers?

Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dom0 is only using a couple of CPU cores (xen management VM). You can verify all existing CPUs via Citrix XenCenter (navigate to the host, then click tap General -> CPUs).

More CPU information is available via "xe host-cpu-list params=all".